# Python Django function got multiple values for argument

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to call a function to print a receipt using Django in an html file. The function has 1 variable print_order_receipt(number) where the number is the order number fetched from Shopify API.
This is the HTML code I did:

```
path('print/<int:number>/', views.print_order_receipt, name="print")
```

And this is the function:

```
def print_order_receipt(number):
order = Order.objects.get(number=number)
printer = Network("192.168.1.100")
printer.text('**********************************************\n')
printer.text('LNKO vous remercie!\n')
printer.text('**********************************************\n')
printer.text('\n')
printer.text('\n')
printer.text('Commande Numero: ')
printer.text(order.number)
printer.text('\n')
printer.text('\n')
printer.text('Montant total a payer: ')
printer.text(order.totalprice + " MAD")
printer.text('\n')
printer.text('Dont taxes: ')
printer.text(order.tax + " MAD")
printer.text('\n')
printer.text('Client: ')
printer.text(order.clientfname + ' ' + order.clientlname)
printer.text('\n')
printer.text('Une facture detaillee a ete envoyee a:\n')
printer.text(order.clientemail)
printer.barcode(order, 'EAN13', 64, 2, '', '')
printer.qr("You can readme from your smartphone")
printer.cut()
```

And these are the 2 HTML versions I tried, both are not working:

```
<td><a href="/print/{{ number }}">Imprimer</a></td>

<td><a href="{% url 'print' {{ number }} %}">Imprimer</a></td>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here!
Here is the Traceback error:

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/print/12500/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\My Laptop\lnko\printer_receipt\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\My Laptop\lnko\printer_receipt\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\My Laptop\lnko\printer_receipt\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /print/12500/
Exception Value: print_order_receipt() got multiple values for argument 'number'
```

Comment: `{% url 'print' {{ number }} %}` this is not correct by the way. Don't use { } inside tag syntax {% %}

Comment: Sorry it was just a mistake that I did correct before having this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of a function-based view is always the request, so:

```
def print_order_receipt(request, number):
    # …
```

Django will make a call like `printer_order_receipt(request, number=12500)`. If your first parameter is `number` then both `request` and `number=12500` will try to set the value for the `number` parameter hence the error.

If you use a django template tag, then you should *not* write variables between curly brackets, you write the URL as:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'print' number %}">Imprimer</a></td>
```

or:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'print' number=number %}">Imprimer</a></td>
```

Comment: So I have to add request in the parameters even though Im not using it? And for the {{ number }} sorry I did remove them it was just a mistake

Comment: @KaïssBouali: yes, the view function is always called with the request as first (positional) parameter.